# Caching pre-rendered templates with GAE Memcache API

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been using this logic to render [templates](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html) in my GAE application:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'page.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

I'm wondering if it's possible (and more efficient) to load the unrendered template text and store it in Memcache.  The `template.render()` method seems to want a file path, so is this even possible?

*Edit*: For clarity, I'm talking about caching the template itself, not the rendered output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google App Engine caches templates out of the box in order to keep your application responsive.

Here is the interesting part of the [template.py](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py) module available in the source code:

```
def render(template_path, template_dict, debug=False):
  """Renders the template at the given path with the given dict of values."""
  t = load(template_path, debug)
  return t.render(Context(template_dict))

template_cache = {}
def load(path, debug=False):
  abspath = os.path.abspath(path)

  if not debug:
    template = template_cache.get(abspath, None) # <---- CACHING!
  else:
    template = None

  if not template:
    directory, file_name = os.path.split(abspath)
    ...
```

As you can see, the only thing to keep in mind is to avoid to set `debug = True` in Production.

Comment: Note that this caches the templates in local instance memory, not memcache, which is a much better idea.

Comment: But can the auto caching in instance memory be controlled? What if you want to show the same rendered page for a full hour?

Comment: OP is talking about template caching and not about content caching; for the latter you can use a memcache layer.